# Scheduling Background jobs in Parse

Tags: ios, parse-platform, background-process

i have searched a lot but can find any thing about parse background jobs scheduling .i am new in parse please give me example how and where to implement background jobs  with scheduler in parse as there is no example any where

Comment: any one can please help me deadline is in this week .any help will be appreciated thank u

Answer (score 1):

You schedule background jobs in the dashboard. Not possible in code

Answer (score -2):

To get detailed knowledge about parse you must go through its guide which is available at https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#top/iOS

As per your question, most of the work occurs in background for parse, for e.g.

```
-if you want to update user detail you can use without completion block:
 PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
    user [@"firstname"] = self.firstnameTextFeild.text;
    [user saveInBackground];

-if you want to update user detail you can use with completion block:
 PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
    user [@"firstname"] = self.firstnameTextFeild.text;
    [user saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
//Do anything you want
}];

-if you want to update user detail even if you are offline:
 PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
    [@"firstname"] = self.firstnameTextFeild.text;
    [user saveEventually]; // This will update user as device gets online
```

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question.